# Why is it wrong to use TypeScript "Function" type

Tags: typescript

Lately I have been reading about proper way of setting types in TS and I stumbled upon `foo: Function` against `foo: ()=>void` notation. It seems to me that many people despise the former, but they don't provide a reasonable answer for it other than their own preferences. Could someone please explain too me how is that a bad thing? Isn't Function type easier to read (and faster to write)? Or there are some drawbacks that I am missing?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-types/#default-options

Comment: This is [documented in the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function); `Function` is an untyped function call and does not catch errors in typing.  Try to assign a function that needs a parameter to a `()=>void` and the compiler will rightly complain; do the same with a `Function` and you get no compiler warning about the potential runtime kablooey you've set up: see [this example](https://tsplay.dev/mb0yBw).   Does that explain it to your satisfaction? If so then I can maybe write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to say "the former" if you mean `Function`.  Even better, just write `Function` if you mean `Function` or `()=>void` otherwise.  Also, can you provide evidence for "It seems to me that many people despise xxx, but they don't provide a reasonable answer for it other than their own preferences."?  Where have you been "reading about [the] proper way of setting types in TS"? It's hard to answer something authoritatively when the question is not clear about the background info.

Comment: I am sorry guys you are of course correct I meant the former and I think jcalz explained it to me perfectly, thank you very much for that.